# How does a class knows if something's going on in one of his variables?

Tags: c++, class, object, methods, architecture

So let's say I have class A and class B

I have an instance of class B in object A

When i'm using some methods of my class B instance, I want it to tell object A if an event X occurs in B. How can I achieve this ?

I don't want the methods to return a value just to tell something happened because there must be another way.

Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Use an __observer__. Also, take a __[tour]__.

Comment: About time C++ had proper properties.

Answer (score 0):

Let's not talk about observer pattern yet. The following code show you how to achieve the purpose:

```
class IChangeHanlder {
public:
    virtual void handleXChanged(int x) = 0;
};


class FirstChangeHanlder : public IChangeHandler {
public:
    void handleXChanged(int x) {
        cout << "First Change Handler: x changed to << x;
    }
}

class SecondChangeHanlder : public IChangeHandler {
public:
    void handleXChanged(int x) {
        cout << "Second Change Handler: x changed to << x;
    }
}

class B {
private:
    int _x;
    vector<IChangeHanlder *> _handlers;
public:
    void setX(int x) {
        _x = x;
        for(IChangeHandler *i : _handlers)
            i->handleXChanged(x);
    }

    void addXChangeHandler(IChangeHandler *handler) {
        _handlers.push_back(handler);
    }
}

class A {
    B _b;
public:
    void Test() {
        IChangeHandler *h1, *h2;
        h1 = new FirstChangeHandler();
        _b.addXChangeHandler(h1);
        _b.setX(10);
        h2 = new SecondChangeHandler();
        _b.addXChangeHandler(h2);
        _b.setX(3);
    }
}
```

In the code above, when _b.x changes, A knows the change happens because in setX function, we notify all the handlers:

```
    void setX(int x) {
        _x = x;
        for(IChangeHandler *i : _handlers)
            i->handleXChanged(x);
    }
```

The method has fancy name "observer pattern", and often illustrated with tons of diagrams and words. The code above simplifies the concept. Hope that helps you understand the pattern.